# getting error in mysql while inserting data in the table

Tags: mysql, ip

```
insert values into emp
("1001","Sahil","Footballer","2017-01-02",10000,99,2),
("1002","Saumya","Army","2017-01-01",10000,100,1),
("1003","Soumya","Doctor","2017-01-03",1000,91,3),
("1004","Rishi","CA","2017-01-04",1001,15,3),
("1005","Anurag","Cricketer","2017-01-05",10001,24,2),
("1006","Ritwik","Don","2017-01-06",10024,13,3),
("1007","Ashish","Manager","2017-01-07",50014,34,4),
("1008","Prateek","Philosopher","2017-01-08",6451,423,4),
("1009","Aniket","Soft Engineer","2017-01-09",5784,901,4),
("1010","Khushi","Musician","2017-01-10",9645,9,2);
```

getting error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values into emp ("1001","Sahil","Footballer","2017-01-02",10000,99,2),
("1002","' at line 1.
```

Please fix this as soon as possible

Comment: Adding imperatives like "Please fix this as soon as possible" [should not be added to questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/) as they will reduce the likelihood that you will receive answers to your question as it is just noise at best, and considered rude at worst.

Comment: What isn't clear about this error message?

Comment: **As soon as possible** you should read about SQL Syntax: `insert  into emp  values ...` not `insert values into emp`

Comment: What does this have to do with `ip`?

Answer (score 1):

I will reply to this despite the rudeness hoping that it as language barrier issue rather than rudeness.

The correct syntax would be:

INSERT INTO emp (Id, Name, profession, date, x, y, z)
VALUES ("1001","Sahil","Footballer","2017-01-02",10000,99,2),
("1002","Saumya","Army","2017-01-01",10000,100,1),

you simply forgot to include the column names you wish to add the values to.

Comment: No, that's not quite it. But close enough.

Comment: What did I overlook?

Comment: It's not a failure to include column names. It's simply incorrect syntax (`values into emp`)

Comment: I didn't even notice that he had mixed the words up in my speed to give an  answer. But you are of course correct.

Comment: Oddly, inclusion of terms like 'asap' tends to make me respond slower (or not at all)